# Copy entire row if CountA<>0 to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy entire row if `CountA <>0` for column J7:AM7 (headers on J6:AM6) and so on till the last used cell is column D and paste the entire row in sheet 1 (A1) one below the another.

```
Sub ABC()
    A = Sheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, "d").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 7 To A    
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(RANGE("J:AM" & i)) <> 0 Then
            Sheets(3).Rows(i).Copy
            B = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Sheets(1).Cells(B + 1, 1).Paste
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for your range `RANGE("J:AM" & i)` there is no sheet specified. And the number part for `J` is missing. It should be `Sheets(3).Range("J" & i & ":AM" & i)`.

I recommend to use meaningful variable names instead of `A` and `B` and declare all your variables properly. Always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

```
Option Explicit 

Public Sub ABC()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Sheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, "d").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 7 To LastRow
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(3).Range("J" & iRow  & ":AM" & iRow)) <> 0 Then
            Sheets(3).Rows(iRow).Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, however it took about 6-7 mins to complete as i have huge now of rows. How do I make a change in the code so that it copies only range A:AM in sheet3 till the last row in column D, instead of copying the entire row and paste it in Sheet1 one below the other? I think this will optimize the code even more.

Please help me out!